# Confused about proof in Basic abstract algebra by Bhattacharya

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

On page 264 , 2nd edition. Theorem 5.1
It says Let M be a free $R$-module with "a basis" $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ Then $M$ is $R$-isomorphic to $R^n$.
Above he is defining the standard basis as the $n$-tuples $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ witch is only one abelian group.

Does he really mean that this works only if M has this particular basis? I think this should be valid for any basis of any  free module. There are a lot more sets that can be made into abelian groups then the $n$-tuples.

The example above states that any infinite cyclic group as a $\mathbb Z$-module has a basis, which contradicts his notation below according to me.

I don't think he means the "standard basis" in the hypothesis of the proof even though he has written it.

Comment: Can you tell us what the theorem is? It's not true that every free module has a finite basis, but a finitely generated free module does.

Comment: Any infinite cyclic group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$, so it has a basis.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Let M be a free R-module with "a basis" {e1,..en}. Then M is R-isomorphic to R^n

Comment: Ah, I thought that was part of the proof, since you wrote "Proof 5.1" instead of "Theorem 5.1." No, he definitely doesn't mean the $e_i$ to be the standard basis of $R^n$, because $M$ might not be represented in that form.

Comment: A free $R$-module $M$ has a basis, by definition.  The basis is a spanning set of $M$ without any nontrivial dependence relations, $\sum r_i e_i = 0$.  The $e_i$ here are the basis elements.  They do not form a group, abelian or otherwise.  They are simply module elements.  Given this basis you can construct a module homomorphism from $M$ to (say) $R^n$ just be specifying the images of the basis elements.  So the map taking $f(e_i)$ to the standard basis element of $R^n$ with $i$th coordinate $1$ and other coordinates zero is a well-defined module homomorphism (it happens to be onto).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a basis $B$ (or in other words being a free module) *means* that the module behaves exactly like $R^{|B|}$, up to isomorphism. So you can do all of your thinking while having $R^{|B|}$ with the standard basis in mind, and then use the assumed isomorphism to argue that all your conclusions are valid for arbitrary free modules too.

For example, this means that any infinite cyclic group *is* $\mathbb Z^1$ (that is, just $\mathbb Z$ itself) up to isomorphism.

Comment: So he means {e1,...en} as any basis for any module not the particular standard basis. I dont understand his choice of letter,can you justify it?

Comment: The point of this notation is that $e_k$ in the module sense will map under the canonical isomorphism to $e_k$ in the Euclidean sense. Perhaps we would prefer $\tilde e_k$, but at some point the author would rather trust the reader to understand the context and avoid the proliferation of tildes.